# AsyncTask progress dialog not appearing in some fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-asynctask

I have some fragments all of them uses very simple asynctasks who mostly look like the same and are derived from the same base task.
In most of them I see the progress dialog circle spinnin while they are executed but in one it doesn't appear despite the fact that the task is correctly executed.

Why? I'm using the default setting only overriding doInBackground and onPostExecute.

Could it be cause by layouts(but in my case they are similar?

This is the code of the asynctask causing the problem(both tasks with and without the progress dialog are child of the same task class)

```
/**
    * AsyncTask che richiede i dati al server
    * @author pc
    *
    */
   class MuroTask extends GetDataTask {


       JSONObject jobject;
       ServerInterface server = new ServerInterface();



    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            jobject = server.runScriptObject(script_name, null);
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }


        return true;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {


    if (success) {
        if (jobject != null){
            if (parseJSON(jobject)){
            isEmpty = false;
            setContentMuro();
            }
            else{
                isEmpty = true;
            }
        }
         else{
             isEmpty = true;
         }
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),R.string.failed_connection, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }


        }

}
```

Comment: can you add some codes?

Comment: Do you use same context in all fragments for AsyncTask? (not ApplicationContext)

Comment: yes, I'm not passing directly a context they are in a fragmentpager in the same activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed it in the fragment class I was

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inf, ViewGroup container, Bundle b){
    frag_view = inf.inflate(R.layout.list_with_margins, container, false);

    return frag_view;

}
```

I removed this part because it wasn't even needed anymore and the loading dialog appeared.

I have no idea of why inflating my own view was hiding the progress dialog

Answer (score 0):

You must use getActivity() as context for your progress dialog AsyncTask in Fragments.

Comment: I'm using the standard progress dialog, I didn't write a line of code for it to show in the other fragments

Comment: you have not mentioned onPreExecute() in your asyntask which generally has code to show Progress dilaog. Without it you will not be able to see a progress dialog

Comment: I'm not overriding onPreExecute() btw solved, read my answer, thanks for your replies

Comment: ok but I posted the entire class and there was no onPreExecute()